# Set default to print only certain pages in MS Word

Tags: microsoft-word, printing

How can I set an MS Word document to only print the first x pages by default? I have a large document, but I don't want people who print it out to accidentally print the whole thing instead of the first 11 pages (which I want them to print).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the only way to do this is by [creating a macro](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/create-a-macro-HP005189420.aspx).

Add your preferred code to your macro, and change X & Y to desired range (in your case 1 & 11).

---

*Use this code if you want to it show the print dialog and allow selection of any range, but just set default to pages X-Y:*

```
Sub FilePrint()
  With ActiveDocument
       ' unprotect
       If .ProtectionType <> wdNoProtection Then
          .Unprotect Password:="snip"
       End If
       .Bookmarks("RunSpellCheckButton").Range.Font.Hidden = True
        With Dialogs(wdDialogFilePrint)
            .Range = wdPrintFromTo
            .From = X
            .To = Y
            .Show
        End With
      .Bookmarks("RunSpellCheckButton").Range.Font.Hidden = False
       ' reprotect
      .Protect Type:=wdAllowOnlyFormFields, NoReset:=True, Password:="snip"
  End With
End Sub
```

*Use this code if you want it to automatically print X-Y pages when running the macro, without showing the print dialog first:*

```
Sub FilePrint()
  With ActiveDocument
       ' unprotect
       If .ProtectionType <> wdNoProtection Then
          .Unprotect Password:="snip"
       End If
       .Bookmarks("RunSpellCheckButton").Range.Font.Hidden = True
      .PrintOut Range:=wdPrintFromTo, From:="X", To:="Y"
      .Bookmarks("RunSpellCheckButton").Range.Font.Hidden = False
       ' reprotect
      .Protect Type:=wdAllowOnlyFormFields, NoReset:=True, Password:="snip"
  End With
End Sub
```

---

Credit: [Jay Freedman (Microsoft MVP)](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/word/thread/2d14608f-58b3-49f1-937b-c54ec559af07/).